# How to insert into a table new records based on info from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, record

I am using SQL Server 2012 on Windows7. I currently have 2 tables.

The first table:

```
DeviceID   DeviceSwVersion   DeviceIPAddr   
1          802               172.26.20.1   
115        800               172.26.18.1   
1234       264               172.26.18.3   
4717       264               172.26.19.2  // <- new   
14157      264               172.26.19.1  // <- new
```

The second table:

```
DeviceIPAddr   Status   TimeStamp (default=getdate())  
172.26.20.1    1        2016-02-09 10:25:01   
172.26.18.1    1        2016-02-09 10:30:12   
172.26.18.3    1        2016-02-09 10:33:08
```

What I need is a SQL query to insert into 2nd table new rows corresponding to the new `DeviceIP` that are now present in the first table. *Only the new* `DeviceIP`s that *are not already there* in the 2nd table.

So, finally the 2nd table should look like this:

```
DeviceIPAddr   Status   TimeStamp // default = getdate()   
172.26.20.1    1        2016-02-09 10:25:01   
172.26.18.1    1        2016-02-09 10:30:12   
172.26.18.3    1        2016-02-09 10:33:08     
172.26.19.2    0        2016-02-10 09:53:00   
172.26.19.1    0        2016-02-10 09:53:01
```

Remark: `Status` column is 0 for new inserted rows and `TimeStamp` is the current date-time (default value filled automatically by getdate() function).

Comment: Try to use trigger for this

Comment: I would try to, but I don't know how. I'm a very beginner in SQL. :( ... Please advise.

Comment: @groenhen , As Paresh already told I think ``AFTER INSERT`` trigger is better solution. As you are a beginner, My answer give you the idea about your required trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a **AFTER INSERT TRIGGER** something like bellow:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_table_1
   ON table_1 
   AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO table_2
   ( DeviceIPAddr,
     Status,
     TimeStamp)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.DeviceIPAddr,
     0,
     getdate() );

END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Merge is another way..

```
 MERGE <[The second table]> t
USING [The first table: ] s
  ON t.DeviceIPAddr    = s.DeviceIPAddr   
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
  INSERT (DeviceIPAddr, Status, Timestamp)
  VALUES (s.DeviceIPAddr,0, getutcdate())
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into secondtable
select deiviceipaddr,0,getdate()
from isttable t1
where not exists(select 1 from secondtable t2 where t1.ipaddress=t2.ipaddress)
```

---one more way

```
insert into secondtable
select deiviceipaddr,status from firsttable
except
select deiviceipaddr,status from secondtable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 INSERT Table2
 SELECT   DeviceIPAddr, 0, getDate()
 FROM    Table1
 WHERE   DeviceIpAddr NOT IN (SELECT DeviceIpAddr FROM Table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert into table2
(DeviceIPAddr, Status, TimeStamp)

SELECT t1.deiviceipaddr, 0, GETDATE()
FROM Table1
Left Outer Join Table2
ON (t1.DeviceIPAddr = t2. DeviceIPAddr)
WHERE t2. DeviceIPAddr IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can use NOT EXISTS() for that, like this:

```
INSERT INTO SecondTable 
(SELECT t.DeviceIpAddr , 0 as status,getdate()
 FROM FirstTable t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from SecondTable s where t.DeviceIpAddr  = s.DeviceIpAddr )
```

Or, you can use NOT IN() like this:

```
 INSERT INTO SecondTable 
(SELECT t.DeviceIpAddr , 0 as status,getdate()
 FROM FirstTable t
 WHERE t.DeviceIpAddr  NOT IN(select distinct s.DeviceipAddr from SecondTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (DeviceID int, DeviceSwVersion int, DeviceIPAddr varchar(11))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (DeviceID, DeviceSwVersion, DeviceIPAddr)
VALUES
    (1, 802, '172.26.20.1'),
    (115, 800, '172.26.18.1'),
    (1234, 264, '172.26.18.3'),
    (4717, 264, '172.26.19.2'),
    (14157, 264, '172.26.19.1')
; 

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE 
    (DeviceIPAddr varchar(11), Status int, TimeStamp varchar(19))
;

INSERT INTO @Table2
    (DeviceIPAddr, Status, TimeStamp)
VALUES
    ('172.26.20.1', 1, '2016-02-09 10:25:01'),
    ('172.26.18.1', 1, '2016-02-09 10:30:12'),
    ('172.26.18.3', 1, '2016-02-09 10:33:08')
```

;
**USING NOT EXISTS**

```
Select TT.DeviceIPAddr,0 Status,getdate() TimeStamp from @Table1 TT 
        where  NOT EXISTS 
                (select 1 from @Table2 T where T.DeviceIPAddr = TT.DeviceIPAddr)
```

OR

**USING EXCEPT**

```
Select TT.DeviceIPAddr,0 AS Status, getdate() AS  TimeStamp from @Table1 TT
EXCEPT 
select T.DeviceIPAddr,0 AS Status, getdate() AS  TimeStamp from @Table2 T
```

Comment: But SO mentioned Date is Default as far as we are filtering the records based on DeviceIPaddress @TheGameiswar